# sendSticker telegram bot

Tags: telegram-bot

Пытался отправить стикер при помощи бота в чат, однако столкнулся с проблемой:
Error 400 Bad Request: there is no sticker in the request. Не понимаю в чем проблема.

```
curl https://api.telegram.org/bot<token>/sendSticker?chat_id=<chat_id>&sticker="CAACAgQAAxkBAAEBSUNfT_WR7Tn46_xh-6Uyd_4vGwdrNAAC6wIAAlGMzwHHJxEAAXAnio8bBA"
```

[image]

Comment: Попробуй убрать кавычки

Comment: @ValeraKvip, к сожаление это не помогает.

Comment: Может id стикера не правильное? Как ты его получил?

Comment: проверил строку, без кавычек всё прекрасно отправляет. `&sticker=CAACAgQAAxkBAAEBSUNfT_WR7Tn46_xh-6Uyd_4vGwdrNAAC6wIAAlGMzwHHJxEAAXAnio8bBA`